# is my 8080 being listened？

Tags: port, ubuntu-10.10

I run the following command on ubuntu 10.10. Could anyone tell me what does the result mean？

> ubuntu@ip-XX-XXX-XX-XXX:~$ netstat -nao | grep 80
>
> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
>   off (0.00/0/0)
>
> tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN
>   off (0.00/0/0)
>
> tcp6       0      0 :::8009                 :::*                    LISTEN
>   off (0.00/0/0)
>
> tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN
>   off (0.00/0/0)

Comment: it means you have something (a web server?) listening on port 8080 of localhost.

Comment: try typing "telnet localhost 8080" and then "GET /" or just pointing your web browser to http://localhost:8080

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have 4 listening open ports. Here, tcp is for Transmission Control Protocol.

**tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:80 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN off (0.00/0/0)** - accept all incoming ipv4 connection on port 80.

**tcp6 0 0 127.0.0.1:8005 :::* LISTEN off (0.00/0/0)** - accept incoming ipV6 connection on localhost loop interface (you can insert packets from localhost only).

**tcp6 0 0 :::8009 :::* LISTEN off (0.00/0/0)**  - accept all incoming ipV6 connection on port 8009.

**tcp6 0 0 :::8080 :::* LISTEN - off (0.00/0/0)** - accept all incoming ipV6 connection on port 8080.

So, your port 8080 is listening, but on ipv6 stack.

Comment: i have issues with those ports few days ago when i install jetty6. To run it on ipv4 stack i add -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true java prop in /etc/default/jetty